# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/vialogic2210/public_html/vialogic.co/index.php on line 112

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, http-status-code-404, hosting

i have the vialogic.co built in wordpress. hosting is on godaddy. htaccess file code is

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|geju.php|plugin-install.php|cong.php|about.php|fun.php|wp-admin.php|TNT.php|trust.php|godsend.php|bak.php|wp-login.php|a.php|wp-zett.php|LV.php|content.php|87.php|)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

when i am trying to open any page,comment,plugins etc in wordpress dashboard it gives me 404 page not found.
in error logs it says

``` Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/vialogic2210/public_ht``ml/vialogic.co/index.php on line 112 ```

What should i do in this case?

opening pages,plugins,comments and all options in wordpress dashbaord but it says

" Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/vialogic2210/public_html/vialogic.co/index.php on line 112 "

Comment: Is this supposed to be the top-level, default index.php WordPress comes with? Because that should not even have 112 lines, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/index.php